# Metric on manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

A Metric, which is a (2,0) tensor on a manifold $M$ that is symmetric and non-degenerate.

A Riemannian Meric is a metric that is positive definite.

I'm reading proposition 13.3 from Lee's intro to smooth manifolds.

I understand that we can prove that every smooth manifold admits Riemannian Metric using partition of unity.

I'm just wondering is it possible to use that same proof to prove that every smooth manifold admits some other metric that is not positive definite?

I don't see how the proof relies on the positive definiteness.

Comment: The proof **does** rely on positive-definiteness: at one point you need to use that a linear combination of positive-definite inner products on a vector space with positive coefficientes is itself a positive-definite inner product, and that is not true if you remove the positive-definiteness.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is cant you just construct some non positive definiteness metric locally and take linear combination of those to construct a global non-positive definite metric?

Comment: My comment above gives the precise reason why you cannot!

Comment: Are you saying that linear combination does not preserve other properties besides positive definiteness?

Comment: I suggest you try to prove it.

Comment: Yes, i proved by defining a riemannian metric on the charts, then use partition of unity to sum things up. Because every term is positive definite, the summation is positive definite, therefore it defines a global metric which is positive definite, therefore riemannian.

Comment: I of course was suggesting that you try to prove that a linear combination with positive coefficients of inner products which are not positive-definite is an inner product, which is what you are assuming is true and, well, is not.

Comment: As a simple example, consider any non positive definite metric on a 2-dimensional vector space: then its opposite is also such a metric and their sum is not.

Comment: So what im seeing from your example is that non-degenerateness is not always preserved with positive linear combination therefore the sum might fail to be a metric..hopefully im right

Comment: Exactly. This is the content of my first comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, because there are differential-topological obstructions to the existence: not all manifolds admit metrics of a given signature.

You can see the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103287/a-existence-problem-of-p-q-metric) for example. The simplest case is that of metrics of signature $(1,n-1)$: they exist iff the tangent bundle contains a $1$-dimensional subbundle, and that occurs iff the Euler class of the manifold is zero.